# Were Suitengu's parents murdered?

Tags: speed-grapher

During Suitengu's flashback of his childhood, he finds both his parents have hanged themselves. However when Kamiya sees them, he almost acts as if he was expecting it (plus there was his timing arriving at the mansion).

One of the requirements for membership of the Roppongi Club was that a member have life insurance, so that if a member couldn't pay what they owed they could get killed and the insurance be collected. We see in the episode where Suitengu's music box breaks that the guy who couldn't pay was hanged to make look like it was a suicide.

I am wondering, were Suitengu's parents murdered and if so, was it by the Tennōzu Group who pushed them into debt?